# PuPHPet - failed dependencies

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I've build basic PuPHPet configuration and tried to run it, but i'm getting warnings like

```
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_php/Service[php5.6-fpm]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

I haven't made any changes to config. On website I only checked instalation of Redis, MongoDB and ElasticSearch (it's important to my app).

What can be wrong?

Config: http://pastebin.com/3JjGwWGS
Log: http://pastebin.com/SAyRy1eW

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting this open issue [here](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2327), and that page links to the workaround [here](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2270).